# Service Workers BackgroundSync and Angular 2

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to integrate service workers BackgroundSync with angular 2.  I followed this article as a beginners guide to service workers [ServiceWorker: A Basic Guide to BackgroundSync](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/backgroundsync)

My main concern is having multiple components with forms, how am I to register each button click in each component to the service worker and keep using angular 2 services to call the server.  In the example above, in the registration of the service worker, he is adding the sync and the call to the server is done through 
**service-worker.js**.

Is there a way that the registration of the sync can be done dynamically in each component where needed and how can I keep using angular 2 services?